# Ajuda para construir um arquivo json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
        arrayPerguntas = [{

            bloco: $("#bloco-num").val(),
            perguntas: [{
                numerodapergunta: numeroDaPergunta[0].value,
                numerodaperguntaSemPonto: retiraPonto(numeroDaPergunta[0].value),
                descricaoQuestao: descricaoQuestao[0].value,
                notapergunta: questao[0].value,
                tipoQuestao: tipoPerg[0].options[tipoPerg[0].selectedIndex].value
            }]
        }];
```

queria adicionar dentro do array `perguntas` e não no arrayPerguntas, ou seja no meu código está adicionando assim:

```
        {
            bloco: "bc-1"
            perguntas: [{
                numerodapergunta: 1,
                numerodaperguntaSemPonto: 1,
                descricaoQuestao: "blabla",
                notapergunta: 1,
                tipoQuestao: "tipo-4"
            }]
        },{

            bloco: "bc-1"
            perguntas: [{
                numerodapergunta: 2,
                numerodaperguntaSemPonto: 2,
                descricaoQuestao: "blablabla2",
                notapergunta: 2,
                tipoQuestao: "tipo-2"
            }]
        }
```

**queria adicionar assim:**

```
      {
            bloco: "bc-1"
            perguntas: [{
                numerodapergunta: 1,
                numerodaperguntaSemPonto: 1,
                descricaoQuestao: "blabla",
                notapergunta: 1,
                tipoQuestao: "tipo-4"
            },{
                numerodapergunta: 2,
                numerodaperguntaSemPonto: 2,
                descricaoQuestao: "blablabla2",
                notapergunta: 2,
                tipoQuestao: "tipo-2"
            }]
        }
```

Comment: Você pode disponibilizar o código que gera esse JSon?

Comment: como é que estás a construir o json? php?

Comment: Podes explicar melhor esses 3 pedaços de código? Podes fazer um jsFiddle? assim fica bem fácil ajudar-te

Answer (score 0):

Porque não tentas isto? 
Vai te ajudar a construir o ficheiro sem erros.

http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/